# Is it possible to create documents and attachments by using Visualforce Page?

Tags: visualforce

Is it possible to create documents and attachments by using Visualforce Page?
    I just want to upload image in "Choose File" button(InputFile tag) Where i can save documents and attachments at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can attach create documents and attachments using VF page.
Sample VF page for inserting Attachment.

```
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Save"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>

  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="File Name"/>
      <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="File"/>
      <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Sample Controller class

```
public class UploadAttchCtr {

    public Attachment attachment {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public UploadAttchCtr() {
        attachment = new Attachment();
    }

    public void upload() {
    attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    attachment.ParentId = '0069000000BNuBc'; //specify the record ID;
    attachment.IsPrivate = true;

    try {
        insert attachment;
    } catch (DMLException e) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Error uploading attachment'));
        //return null;
    }

    Document document = new Document();
    document.AuthorId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    document.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId(); // put it in running user's folder
    document.Body = attachment.body;
    document.Name = attachment.Name;        
    try {
      insert document;
    } catch (DMLException e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading file'));
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Himanshu you are creating attachment not document file.

Comment: @user24524 Yes in my sample i am creating attachment. you can also add Document in the Similar manner.
Use following for Documents :  http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/uploading-a-document-using-visualforce-and-a-custom-controller

Comment: I mentioned in my question here i have to create document and attachment in single input file.Means I don't want to make individual file for document and attachment.

Comment: You mean, you need to create both Attachment and Document from single input file?

Comment: Yes, You got it!

Comment: please see updated code above. Let me know if it works :)